# How to Deserialize JSON into dictionary with custom key

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net, json-deserialization

How to use `Json.NET` and convert a `class` into a `Dictionary`? The key of the dictionary is the `seed["name"]` in the `json` file.

Can anyone help? Thanks alot!

Sample JSON

```
"Seed": [
    {
        "name": "Cheetone",
        "growthrate": 1,
        "cost": 500
    },
    {
        "name": "Tortone",
        "growthrate": 8,
        "cost": 100
    }
]
```

My code

```
public class SoilStat
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "growthrate")]
    public int growthRate;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cost")]
    public int cost;
}

public class DataLoader : MonoSingleton<DataLoader>
{
    public string txt;
    Dictionary<string, SoilStat> _soilList = new Dictionary<string, SoilStat>();

    // error on this line
    _soilList = array.ToDictionary(t => t["name"].ToString(), t => new SoilStat { cost = (int)t["cost"], growthRate = (int)t["growthrate"] });
}
```

It throws exception

> ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: value
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.EnsureValue (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken value) (at Assets/Plugins/JsonDotNet/Source/Linq/JToken.cs:349)
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.op_Explicit (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken value) (at Assets/Plugins/JsonDotNet/Source/Linq/JToken.cs:541)
>   DataLoader.m__3 (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken t) (at Assets/Script/Util/DataLoader.cs:112)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[JToken,String,SoilStat] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[JToken,String,SoilStat] (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2 elementSelector)

Comment: Why don't you add name as a property under SoilStat, import the JSON to a SoilStat object and create a new dictionary entry using _soilList.add( mySoilList.name, mySoilList);? Will make it easier to understand future SoilStat objects as well.

Answer (score 3):

You might be doing something wrong in the `array` formation.

Let's say this is your class (You can remove the `JsonProperty`s)

```
public class SoilStat
{
    public int GrowthRate { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
}
```

Then this code works fine with your data

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
var jsonString = "<Read the json as string>";
Dictionary<string, SoilStat> _soilList = JObject.Parse(jsonString)["Seed"]
    .ToDictionary(s => (string)s["name"], 
                  s => new SoilStat { Cost = (int)s["cost"], 
                                      GrowthRate = (int)s["growthrate"] });
```